# CATIA-VBA error: Function or interface marked restricted ... automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, catia

I've recorded a line creation in a VBA macro file, and it generated the following code:

```
Sub CATMain()
    Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument
    Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    Dim part1 As Part
    Set part1 = partDocument1.Part
    Dim bodies1 As Bodies
    Set bodies1 = part1.Bodies
    Dim body1 As Body
    Set body1 = bodies1.Item("PartBody")
    Dim sketches1 As Sketches
    Set sketches1 = body1.Sketches
    Dim originElements1 As OriginElements
    Set originElements1 = part1.OriginElements
    Dim reference1 As Reference
    Set reference1 = originElements1.PlaneYZ
    Dim sketch1, sketch1Variant As Sketch *
    Set sketch1 = sketches1.Add(reference1)
    Dim arrayOfVariantOfDouble1(8)
    arrayOfVariantOfDouble1(0) = 0#
    ...
    arrayOfVariantOfDouble1(8) = 1#
    Set sketch1Variant = sketch1
    sketch1Variant.SetAbsoluteAxisData **
    arrayOfVariantOfDouble1
    part1.InWorkObject = sketch1
    Dim factory2D1 As Factory2D
    Set factory2D1 = sketch1.OpenEdition()
    Dim geometricElements1 As GeometricElements
    Set geometricElements1 = sketch1.GeometricElements
    Dim axis2D1 As Axis2D
    Set axis2D1 = geometricElements1.Item("AbsoluteAxis")
    Dim line2D1 As Line2D
    Set line2D1 = axis2D1.GetItem("HDirection")
    line2D1.ReportName = 1
    Dim line2D2 As Line2D
    Set line2D2 = axis2D1.GetItem("VDirection")
    line2D2.ReportName = 2
    Dim point2D1 As Point2D
    Set point2D1 = factory2D1.CreatePoint(21.285706, -30.501825)
    point2D1.ReportName = 3
    Dim point2D2 As Point2D
    Set point2D2 = factory2D1.CreatePoint(112.826553, -68.875053)
    point2D2.ReportName = 4
    Dim line2D3 As Line2D
    Set line2D3 = factory2D1.CreateLine(21.285706, -30.501825, 112.826553, -68.875053)
    line2D3.ReportName = 5
    line2D3.StartPoint = point2D1
    line2D3.EndPoint = point2D2
    sketch1.CloseEdition
    part1.InWorkObject = body1
    part1.Update
End Sub
```

Now
The issue is that when i run the code as is after recording I get the following error:

> Error in loading dll.

Than I add sketch1Variant object at line * and run the code again.
This time I get the

> "Function or interface marked restricted, or the function uses an automation type not supported in Visual Basic" error for line **.

I don't know what's wrong.
Any info is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule is this: When using VBA, any CATIA method which takes an array as an argument, or returns through an argument must be called on a variant object.

You have declared Sketch1Variant as Sketch. And SetAbsoluteAxisData takes an array as an argument.

What you want is this:

```
Dim Sketch1 as Sketch

Dim Sketch1Variant as Variant
```

(or just leave the "as variant" part off).

With this change you should be able to get past your problem.

In the future please do a web search first, because this is a VERY common question. coe.org is a good site to search.

Comment: Hi C, You can't find out there to much documentation about CATIA-VBA.
I've posted on coe too, but nothing. This was my last chance.So, thank you.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's called 'Late Binding'. The disadvantage is that you would have no intellisense on the variant object type.