# VBA Programming in CATIA

Tags: vba, selection, catia

I have 2 parts in an assembly and I need to subtract one from one. Interactively, I use "Split" command, using the splitting element (a face in the subtracting part). Are there any ways to do it automatically through VBA in CATIA?
I tried using SelectElement2, SelectElement3, SelectElement4 but it didn't work as an error occured repetitively: "Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic."

Code: (Error occur at "SelectElement4, if I change to SelectElent2 or 3, it will still the same error)

```
Set documents1 = CATIA.Documents
Dim partDocument2 As PartDocument
Set partDocument2 = documents1.Item("Chi_Tiet_2")

Dim oSel_2 As Selection
Set oSel_2 = partDocument2.Selection
    
Dim InputObjectType(1)
InputObjectType(0) = "HybridShapeCircle"
InputObjectType(1) = "Face"
Status = oSel_2.SelectElement4(InputObjectType, "Select a circle or a face", False)
MsgBox Status
If (Status = "Normal") Then
    oSel_2.Add oSel_1.Item2(1)
    oSel_2.Copy
End If

Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument
Set partDocument1 = documents1.Item("Chi_tiet_1")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to use _AssemblyFeature_? For restricted functions see e.g. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44030486/17172829)

Comment: I added my code above, the error occurs at SelectElement4 (so does 2, 3). I want to use VBA programming to automatically subtract one part from one another in the assembly context. And yes, Split command is a kind of AssemblyFeature, right?

Comment: Dimension our selection as _Object_ (see also [here](https://v5vb.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/restricted-interfaces/) )

Comment: Yesss, this is exactly what I need to tackle my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is famous, you don't have to use "as selection". It will use an other VBA references, other than CATIA references.

```
  Sub Main()
    
    'dim s as selection => don't use this, that's bug with other VBA references
    Set s = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
    s.Clear
    
    Dim Filters(0)
    Filters(0) = "Face"
    Status = s.SelectElement2(Filters, "Select a feature", True)
    If (Status = "Cancel") Then Exit Sub
    
    MsgBox s.Item(1).Value.Name
    
    End Sub
```

---

check my website : https://www.catiavb.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I addressed the problem!